# Self Referencing Class

Tags: javascript, class, this

I'm learning JS classes and have run into an issue.  I cannot figure out how to self-reference my class variables (set in the constructor) when I lose this context, like after a Promise.

For example:

```
class myClass{
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        doSomething().then(doSomethingElse)
    }

    doSomething(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            resolve("myAsyncName")
        })
    }

    doSomethingElse(value){
        this.name = value;
    }
}
```

In the doSomethingElse function, I'll get an error that this is undefined or cannot set name on it.  I have tried using setting self = this in the constructor which works but breaks if I use the class more than once.  I simply need to be able to reference variables set in my constructor.  I've tried searching many posts and reading a plethora of articles on how to use this, and bind, but I cannot find the pattern I need to use in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the context that `doSomethingElse` is being called from. In your example, the `this` used in `doSomethingElse` will be referencing the context of `then`, not your class.

There are a couple of ways to get around this problem:

**1. Binding the method to the class itself at all times.**

```
constructor(name) {
  this.name = name;

  // binding the `this` context
  this.doSomethingElse = this.doSomethingElse.bind(this);
  // the this in doSomethingElse will always refer the class now
  doSomething().then(doSomethingElse)
}

doSomethingElse() {
```

**2. Using the ES6 fat arrow which lexically bind their context**

```
constructor(name) {
  this.name = name;
  doSomething().then(() => this.doSomethingElse())
}
```

**3. Using the `transform-class-properties` for `babel` (for advanced users)**

Now this one is not part of the official ecmascript spec yet, so I do not encourage using it. I am going to assume that you are, or at some point will be, using `babel`. If not, that is totally okay!

With this plugin you should be able to write something like:

```
class myClass{
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    // no need to change anything here
    doSomething().then(doSomethingElse)
  }

  doSomething(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        resolve("myAsyncName")
    })
  }

  // notice the fat arrow syntax here. `this` will always be
  // referencing myClass
  doSomethingElse = (value) => {
    this.name = value;
  }
}
```

I highly recommend reading Kyle Simpson's *You Don't Know JS: this & object prototypes* on this topic.

- https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Good luck with your journey learning Javascript!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `bind` your `doSomethingElse` function to `this`

i.e

```
this.doSomething().then(this.doSomethingElse.bind(this))
```

Alternatively, you can use arrow function in your `.then`

i.e

```
this.doSomething().then(value => this.doSomethingElse(value));
```